# Adding pages to terminal applications

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, terminal, application, development

I can explain my problem with an example, let us take an example of
`man` command, when we run this command in the terminal it opens the page in a new window, you cannot see what you had done before, in your terminal. How does one make that?

I am working on a terminal application, I want it to work in a similar way when I type in the name of the application, it should open up with on a new page.

edit:
Example of Vim, where when we type `vim` we open vim in the terminal, it has it's interface on the screen. How can I do that with the application I am making.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking about is called the alternate screen buffer, and applications switch to and from the alternate screen by sending ESC codes to the terminal.

If your app is using an ncurses library, there will be functions to do this.  If you want to do it from a shell script, you can use `tput` to send the appropriate codes.

```
tput smcup  # switch to alt screen

tput rmcup  # switch back from alt screen
```

NOTE: most, but not all, terminal emulators support this.  Those that don't (or which have it disabled, which is an option in some terminal emulators) just ignore the codes.

Comment: How can I do this in Python?

Comment: use a python curses library (e.g. the python standard library [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) module). Or a library that provides similar terminal handling functions (like [Notcurses](https://nick-black.com/dankwiki/index.php/Notcurses))

Comment: BTW, see also [Curses Programming with Python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I just edited my question, I think I am not able to explain what I am wanting to ask. Please check my new edit.

Comment: your updated question does not require any changes to my answer, or to my comments about python libraries.

Comment: Alright then, I will try this out, right now. Thanks a lot for the input.